# How can I put a delay on the same subsequent action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

Using redux-toolkit, rxjs, redux-observable

I want to add a 1-second delay between the same action if they are within a short period of time.

A naive example:

if you click a button that displays a pop-up 10 times really quickly, then I want to only show all ten pop-ups but only one pop-up for a second before showing the next pop-up.

let's say the button dispatches an action. is there a way to observe the stream of actions coming in and add a delay?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for debouncing or throttling. Think this we can't implement directly using redux toolkit (that library not intended for this purpose). You might need to use some library like lodash or implement by own

Comment: there is a very loose similarity between my need and debounce/throttle but unfortunately those aren't what I'm looking for. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: do you mean `delay` in rxjs?

Comment: in a sense yes, but I want to catch the stream of one particular action. so, using my example above, if I press the button 10 times, then I want to be able to delay each action by a second 

but as far as i know, for epics, it's actions in and actions out so I can't just set an arbitrary delay.. and I can't dispatch the same action from it.. so more so i want to just observe the stream of incoming actions and set a delay